# Something similar like pagination

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have a `div` and inside the `div` there are other `div` elements. 
On the left and the right side there will be a previous and next button.
When I click the right button the elements inside the ´div´ container will be moved to the left for a specified amount of pixels. <strike>I need to use [Custom Elements](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements) to build the element and of course [Shadow DOM](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom).</strike>

**How is this kind of implementation called? What's the word for it? It's not called pagination or gallery slider.**

Comment: Sounds very theoretical to me - do you want to use a library such as React or Vue? Why don't you create a minimum example with plain HTML and Javascript and then think about the rest?

Comment: Thanks for using Stack Overflow! One of our policies here is that we don't write code for people from scratch, so you're unlikely to get help unless you try something on your own first. If you get stuck when trying on your own, feel free to post a question about *that* and we'll be happy to help you debug it. In the meantime, there are plenty of resources for implementing JavaScript pagination if you search for those exact words on your favorite search engine.

Comment: @IronFlare I'm not looking for a ready-to-use implementation. I'm looking for the word to describe this. Sorry.

Comment: @Alex You might also be looking for a "gallery" or a "gallery slider".

Comment: @IronFlare: How do you call it, when there are for example 5 elements displayed, 1 element from the left disappears when you click the next button and 1 element from the right side gets added.

Comment: @IronFlare it's for sure not called slider gallery or gallery.

Comment: Please provide a link to an example if you can find one

Comment: @NathanFries https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ for example center mode

Comment: That would be called a Carousel

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I added a link in my answer to a GitHub project with a carousel made with custom elements

Comment: Thank you, now I can study the code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not too hard, but you need to understand what the Shadow DOM is and how to create a custom element. What you are referring to is a Web Component (Shadow DOM and Custom Elements). The functionality seems consistent to what is commonly referred to as a "Carousel". [Here is a good reference for Web Components.](https://css-tricks.com/an-introduction-to-web-components/) I think the final product should look something like this if I understand correctly.

[Here is a link to GutHub with a Carousel built with Web Component Spec](https://github.com/ciampo/macro-carousel)

```
<custom-div>
    // child <div>'s
</custom-div>
```

Then you need to define your custom element in JS using the custom element spec.

```
class customDiv extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.attachShadow({
            mode: 'open'
        })
    }
    connectedCallback() {
        let template = document.createElement('template')
        template.innerHTML = `
<style>
    // your custom element styles
</style>
<div>
    <slot name="1"></slot> // this is where the slotted divs in your HTML end up
    <slot name="2"></slot>
    <slot name="3"></slot>
</div>`
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true))
    }
}

customElements.define('customElement', customDiv)
```

Then we can come back to the HTML and add the `<div>` elements. You can add the names `slots` to your `<div>` elements to define where they land inside the custom element.

```
<custom-div>
    <div slot="1">Content 1</div>
    <div slot="2">Content 2</div>
    <div slot="3">Content 3</div>
</custom-div>
```

From here you would implement the gallery slider like any other gallery, just inside the web component.

Comment: Please do not reward questions that do not show any research/implementation effort whatsoever by answering.

Comment: @connexo Actually, he didn't because I already knew how to do the part with Custom Elements. I'm just looking for a **word**. I edited the question.

Comment: This is not a complete answer and is definitely appropriate given the question. He is asking "I don't know what to call this but I need it to do X and use Y Technology to accomplish it". I was simply trying to help define for him what X and Y actually are.

Comment: @NathanFries Thank you for that, we need more people like you! But in this case, I was stupid enough to ask the question wrong.

Comment: @Alex You weren't stupid. Asking a quality question on Stack Overflow is hard. Just take it as a lesson and more forward :)